# Logging in issues in Razor pages

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, razor-pages

I have a problem with logging in. Before that, I created a Register page, and it works fine, it inserts the user into the database. I have been using Identity for logging in.

When I try to log in, I enter the correct username and password, but for some reason, it doesn't work. I have also debugged and placed breakpoints in the `OnPostAsync` method, and I can see that it enters the else branch where it says `ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.")`, but it doesn't display it on the UI as before. Here is my code.

```
// Licensed to the .NET Foundation under one or more agreements.
// The .NET Foundation licenses this file to you under the MIT license.
#nullable disable

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Biblioteka.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

        public LoginModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<LoginModel> logger)
        {
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        [TempData]
        public string SuccessMessage { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
        ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
        /// </summary>
        public class InputModel
        {
            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Username")]
            public string UserName { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            ///     This API supports the ASP.NET Core Identity default UI infrastructure and is not intended to be used
            ///     directly from your code. This API may change or be removed in future releases.
            /// </summary>
            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/");

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    returnUrl = "../../../Pages/Pocetna";
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                    {
                        return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                    }
                    if (result.IsLockedOut)
                    {
                        _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Account is locked out. Please try again later.");
                        return Page();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                        return Page();
                    }
                }
            }
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you don't see the error like: Invalid login attempt  https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrDqV.png?

Comment: The issue is that it says 'Invalid login attempt,' but it's not being displayed, and my goal is to successfully log in.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have this line:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
```

Put above line in the form like:

```
<form id="account" method="post">
    <h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
    <hr />
     <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div> 
    <div class="form-floating">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ReturnUrl" />
        <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" autocomplete="username" aria-required="true" />
        <label asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-label"></label>
        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
     ...
```

Then  'Invalid login attempt,' will be displayed.

Besides, remember to  check your email to confirm your account.
You can by click "click here to confirm your account" in RegisterConfirmation page

[image]

**or** set the `EmailConfirmed` column true to confirm your account.

[image]